# Is it a way to free up resources on Oracle 9i?

Tags: plsql, rman

My Oracle 9i database is organized in "ArchiveLog" mode. I am trying to recover space because the virtual machine on which this base is installed has been badly sized, and it is reaching saturation.
I have executed the command under **RMAN**:

```
DELETE ARCHIVELOG ALL COMPLETED BEFORE 'SYSDATE-100';
```

But I have the impression that this is not enough, what should I do in addition to free up more storage resources on the machine?
The virtual machine can't be increased in size, I have to settle for performing database operations only.

Answer (score 0):

There are massive ways to solve your problem. But ... the easiest way is:

- Risky way (no backup at all)

  rman> crosscheck backup;
  rman> crosscheck copy;
  rman> delete noprompt expired backup;
  rman> delete noprompt expired copy;
  rman> delete noprompt backup;
  rman> delete noprompt copy;
  rman> delete noprompt archivelog all;